# Is it legal to copy site content when providing link to original

Tags: copyright, internet

Lets say I have a website and the content on my website originates for the most part from other websites. But when the content is from an other website i provide a link to this original content with the notification that the original content is located on said link.

I could say my website sort of functions like a search engine except in my "search engine" the content of my "search results" is also available.

Am I allowed to do this?

If extra information or clarification is needed please let me know!

**Edit** The "Is Google legal" question does not answer my question, as explained in the answer I am asking about a large portion of a websites content where as Google only displays a small snippet of a webiste.

Comment: This is what archive.org does.  Possibly related: "[is Google legal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14733/is-google-legal)"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Google legal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/14733/is-google-legal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First I should point out that the Google question is about a different situation, the "snippet" issue where a tiny part of a web page is redistributed, where the issue of resolved in the US by appeal to the "fair use" defense. The proposed scenario as written here is broader since it would go beyond a couple of lines, and goes up to the limit of copy an entire web page. That is copyright infringement, with or without an associated link. Copyright protection is not just about attribution, it is about control. If you can limit your copying appropriately, you may survive under a [fair use](https://law.stackexchange.com/tags/fair-use/info) analysis; but you need to hire a lawyer with experience in copyright litigation to vet your notions of what is "a small amount" etc.

Comment: To be clear, are you asserting that archive.org is in violation of the copyright laws?  Also, why would Google question not be related?  The question is not about whether it redistributes copies of sites.  It has to make copies of full content of sites to index that content.

Comment: What muddies these waters is that because of how content is published on the Web, each view of it requires a full copy to be made by the person viewing it.  So making it available to be viewed is tantamount to soliciting others to copy it.

Comment: No because the law also contains an exemption for an archive which is what achive.org is. The Google question is not unrelated, it is distinguishable: the OP is not asking "Why isn't Google in trouble", he is asking "Can I do this thing that is different from what Google does". Unless you are archive.org, you can't just copy a web page and add a link, saying "Here's that's on that web page".

Comment: but that's what a web browser does.  it makes a copy and (usually) allows you to see where that copy came from.  i effectively made 3 points.  and you addressed 2 of them.  what about this 3rd one?  isn't publishing on the web tantamount to soliciting others to make copies (unless it's protected by a time-limiting DRM scheme)?

Comment: I take it you're asking "how is it legal to read a web page, given how web pages work?". That's not what I assume the OP is after, but it's a credible separate question.

Comment: @user6726 you are correct that is what I am asking.

Comment: "unless you are archive.org..." might be more precisely stated as "unless you are doing the same thing archive.org is doing...."

Comment: @grovkin soliciting people to make copies for a certain limited purpose is not the same as granting them a license to make copies for any other purpose.

Comment: @phoog, first of all, you don't get to specify a purpose when you serve a webpage over a network connection.  But even if you did, reproduction would have to be allowed or it couldn't be transmitted over proxies or CDN's.  Technically speaking, reproduction has to be performed by every intermediate server.

Comment: @grovkin you absolutely *do* get to specify a purpose when you serve a web page: the allowed purpose is distributing the content over the network and viewing it.  My point is that allowing reproduction for the purpose of serving a web page to a browser -- which is implicit in publishing a web page -- does not imply any additional permission to copy the page.  If it did, media companies would be unable to protect their paywalled content from people who buy it and republish it.

Comment: @phoog there is nothing in the http protocol to specify the purpose for which the content is delivered.  It's a response to a request for a named content.  The paywalled content is protected by additional restrictions imposed by DMCA.  It is the act of putting additional restrictions of paywall that gives any content behind the paywall the status of being further protected.  "paywall" as such means that an authentication token (acquired under terms which may impose restrictions) must be presented when requesting the content.

Comment: @user6726 also, I am not sure that archive.org fits the definition of "archival purposes."  It doesn't just provide backup for the purposes of the owners of the archive.org site.  It makes available reproductions of the content of other sites and it often (maybe even usually) does so after the content is no longer made available by the original authors.

Comment: @phoog in fact the very reason for existence of DMCA seems to be allow to have a mechanism for limitation of purpose (through digital restrictions).  But simply making content available over http protocol, to anyone who would request it, does not create any such restriction.

Comment: @phoog if it helps, you can think of simple http access as viewing every site in "incognito" mode.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107531/discussion-between-phoog-and-grovkin).